# Mixed Content: The page at .... This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS

Tags: flask-socketio, ngrok

I was following this guide:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/add-a-websocket-route-to-your-flask-2-x-application

My end goal is to use WebSockets in a Python project. I followed the guide and everything worked flawlessly. But as I tried to create a tunnel to NGROK, I got the following error:

> (index):12 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://b2a4-2001-6b0-1-1041-a481-75bd-808c-bbe1.ngrok-free.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://b2a4-2001-6b0-1-1041-a481-75bd-808c-bbe1.ngrok-free.app/action'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

in the console.

I then attempted to use the following command when tunneling to ngrok:

First Gunicorn:

```
$ gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 4 --threads 100 app:app
```

and then

```
$ ngrok http --scheme=http  5000
```

And now I get this error when I access the ngrok-page that is generated:

> ERR_NGROK_3200
> Tunnel 0533-2001-6b0-1-1041-a481-75bd-808c-bbe1.ngrok-free.app not found

here is my app.py

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@sock.route('/action')
def echo(sock):
    while True:
        data = sock.receive()
        if data == 'left':
            print('left')
        if data == 'right':
            print('right')
        if data == 'forward':
            print('forward')
        if data == 'back':
            print('back')
```

and my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drone</title>
  </head>
  <script>
     
    
     var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host + '/action');

     function sendText(button) {

     var text = button.value; // Get the value of the button
     socket.send(text); // Send the text to the server
   }
   </script>
  <body>
    <h1>Drone Controller</h1>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <br>
    <button value="left" onclick="sendText(this)">Left</button>
  <button value="right" onclick="sendText(this)">Right</button>
  <button value="back" onclick="sendText(this)">Back</button>
  <button value="forward" onclick="sendText(this)">Forward</button>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

files organized like the following:

```
 Main Folder
  app.py
  templates
     index.html
```

Comment: Have you tried using https and wss? That's the proper way to use Ngrok, at least that's what I always do. I don't think it makes sense to downgrade the security of the tunnel by disabling encryption.